# How to change weechat join/leave colours?

Tags: linux, chat, irc, theming

In Weechat, I'm familiar with where most of the look/colour settings are, but I cannot seem to find the setting for the "has joined" and "has quit" messages. Any assistance would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the last 2 versions of Weechat, those colors are not part of the **[color]** section under the `weechat.conf` config. They're actually under `irc.conf`, under **[color]**, and set as `message_join` and `message_quit`. You can change these from within weechat by typing:

```
/set irc.color.message_join <color>
/set irc.color.message_quit <color>
```

Remember to type `/save` to save your changes.

This has been the case for Weechat 0.3.6 and higher, and pretty sure 0.3.5 had a unified config file (everything under weechat.conf).